Can I paint the interior of cinder block walls?
I have an exterior garage I am renovating. I have painted the exterior cinder block with white elastomeric paint to repel water. I’d like to paint the interior so it’s not a plain grey color. I keep reading conflicting information whether or not one can do this. I read both that it’s okay to paint with elastomeric or other paint but I’ve also heard that if you do that, it could trap moisture and cause mold and decay. Can I paint the interior cinder block walls for aesthetic reasons (there is no water leak that I know of) or am I better off leaving them bare? Thank you!

Why not paint the inside with plain flat paint that does is not waterproof, by its nature?

cinder blocks are porous, so if water gets in it will stay for long time

There's no problem painting the inside—your likely paint choices won't be making the CMU waterproof.

There are hundreds of thousands of home in Florida that are constructed with block.  The far majority of these have garages that have the interior and exterior of the block painted.
In over 30 years of living here and being involved with home renovation and construction, I have never heard of, or witnessed that the act of painting interior and exterior block causes a problem.
This sounds like one of those things from the internet has has no research, science or truth behind it.

Painting won't cause a problem but it also won't stop water intrusion. If there's sufficient pressure to push water into the block then there's sufficient pressure to bubble and peel the coating
